# "-bash: telnet: command not found " error?

Tags: linux, telnet

I have the following services running:

```
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
syslog          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
tcsd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
vsftpd          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
xinetd          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

xinetd based services:
        chargen-dgram:  off
        chargen-stream: off
        daytime-dgram:  off
        daytime-stream: off
        discard-dgram:  off
        discard-stream: off
        echo-dgram:     off
        echo-stream:    off
        tcpmux-server:  off
        telnet:         on
        time-dgram:     off
        time-stream:    off
```

why i still got "-bash: telnet: command not found " error?

Thanks

Comment: telnet is actually a client utility not a service, which is why it doesn't appear in the services list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The RHEL/CentOS 5.4 telnet client is installed at `/usr/kerberos/bin/telnet`.  Your $PATH variable thus needs `/usr/kerberos/bin` listed.  (Preferably before /usr/bin)  If for some reason you don't have that file installed, it's part of the package `krb5-workstation`.  Installing that package manually or via YUM should give you what you need.

You can check quick with `which telnet` to see if it's found anywhere in your path.  `echo $PATH` to see what directories are being checked, and `rpm -q krb5-workstation` to see if you have the package installed.


--Christopher Karel

Comment: How about RHEL 6? I have same issue on RHEL 6 and there is no such package (krb5-workstation) nor is such a folder as /usr/kerberos/bin

Comment: On Amazon Linux 2, I have installed krb5-workstation and still cannot find any references to telnet. The folder /usr/kerberos does not exists. I got it to work running "yum install telnet"

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a telnet client installed? Sounds like you only have the daemon installed currently... either that or your environment is setup wrong. Ie, the command telnet does not appear anywhere defined in $PATH

Comment: i am on centos 5.4

Comment: yum install telnet
or if your path is incorrect just run /usr/bin/telnet

Answer (score 0):

In alpine docker image, to install telnet

```
apk update
apk add busybox-extras
```