# Telnet client on redhat linux

Tags: linux, linux-networking, telnet

I am trying to install a telnet client in Red hat linux server which doesn't have internet connectivity.

**Red hat linux version**

```
less /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

when i did some research, i got this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/175041/bash-telnet-command-not-found-error)  from serverfault.com

As per suggestion , i have ran the command  **rpm -q krb5-workstation** and got the following output

```
krb5-workstation-1.10.3-10.el6_4.4.x86_64
```

Does this mean that krb5 workstation is already installed? If yes, what are the steps that i need to follow enable telnet.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have no Internet connection, you will need to download the RPM, move the RPM to a USB stick or something, put that USB stick into the new server and the install the telnet rpm. Another option would be if you have an internal satellite server, internal repo or something to get the package from.

Normally you would just do a:

yum install telnet

and that would give you the client. I do not see a dependency (like kerberos) on loading this RPM when I try and load the telnet client on my box.

Answer (score 1):

If `rpm -q` lists the package, it is installed. Try starting that specific telnet binary with its full path as mentioned in the answer you linked to: `/usr/kerberos/bin/telnet`. If that works, add it to your $PATH if that's the binary you want to use.

I doubt that you need the telnet included with Kerberos, though. There is a separate telnet package as well. At least on [earlier versions of CentOS](http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-install-telnet-client-on-centos-6-3/), the package is there.

If you can retrieve the package (I'm not familiar with how RHEL subscriptions work and whether they allow you to download package files from another machine), try downloading that telnet package, transferring it to the server in question and installing manually:

```
rpm -i telnet_xxxxx.rpm
```